# Ionic - View Leave Events not getting called if close the tab from browser or press home button from mobile

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

$ionicView.leave not getting triggered if i close the tab from browser or press home button from mobile device. I have been strucked in this from a while.

It is getting called if i leave the screen within the app. What i want is that when user press the home button or leave the tab function called.

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function(){

        Meteor.settings.public.global_stop_pool_messages = '';
        Meteor.settings.public.global_stop_pool_messages = true;
        //START CLOSE CHAT
        Meteor.call("closeChat", vm.chat_data, function(error, result){
          if(error){
            vm.chat_data.curr_secured_session_id = null;
                Toastr.show(error.reason, 'error');
                return false;
          } else {
            Meteor.settings.public.global_stop_pool_messages = '';
            Meteor.settings.public.global_stop_pool_messages = true;
            vm.chat_data.curr_secured_session_id = null;
          }
        }); 
        vm.chat_data = {
          last_message_id : 0,
          close_chat : true
        }

        /// START FEtCHING AGENT MESSAGES BY CALLING GET PENDING MESSAGES CALL
        Meteor.setTimeout(function(){
            ///
            Meteor.settings.public.global_stop_pool_messages = '';
            Meteor.settings.public.global_stop_pool_messages = true;
            Meteor.call("poolPendingMessagesOfChat", vm.chat_data, function(error, result){
              if(error){

              } else {

              }
            });
            ///
          }, 1 * 1000);
        });
```

Comment: Could you post some example code? How are you utilizing the `$ionicView.leave` event in your code?

Comment: @Dexter post updated

Answer (score 0):

The event you are listening for is describes as following:

> The view has finished leaving and is no longer the active view. This event will fire, whether it is cached or destroyed.

But the view is still the active view but the website or app is no longer in the foreground. If you are running Ionic as an app instead of inside a web browser you can use the [events](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova/events/events.pause.html) that Cordova provides such as `pause` to find out if someone has pressed the home button since the app will be paused due to being in the background.

Since you are using Angular-Meteor i would recommend you look at [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/) documentation that shows how you register on Cordova events using `$ionicPlatform`.